# Class declaration bug (NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: java

Please advise me what's wrong with this class declaration:

**ExchEngine.java**

```
package engine;

public class ExchEngine {

    public ExchEngine() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExchEngine engine = new ExchEngine();

    }
}
```

When I compile this file, I always get exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test_engine/ExchEngine
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test_engine.ExchEngine
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Exception in thread "main"
```

This seems very weird that ExchEngine.java is inside a package and it cannot run itself. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your source file in a directory called "engine", since that's the package name of gave it.

Compile the file with `javac engine/ExchEngine.java` and run it with `java engine.ExchEngine`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is `engine.ExchEngine`. Something somewhere is looking for `test_engine.ExchEngine`, and is causing this error when it fails to do so. You presumably need to change the two so that they match.

Comment: The first line of the code should be test_engine.
Sorry for typo

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a compile time problem, it is a run time error.

Need more information. For instance, how are you trying to run it? In Eclipse?

If in Eclipse:
You may need to clean the project. Or you might be trying an old run configuration from before you changed the package.

Comment: I run it in Eclipse. I think there is something wrong in classpath. 
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=56849

Comment: @aladine, in Eclipse, click "Project > clean" and then use the dialog that pops up to clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

If your using an IDE, reconfigure the project, mainly where it looks for the Main method. Clean, rebuild, restart, do what ever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the classpath when running your application

Assuming after compiling, you have the following directory structure:

```
./test_engine/ExchEngine.class
```

then run it like so:

```
java -cp . test_engine.ExchEngine
```